# Customizing the scale of Google Maps JavaScript API?

Tags: google-maps

We are using Google Maps API to show a large map with plots on it. The map is displayed on the wall using a big TV.

Is there a way I can increase the font size? The TV has lots of pixels per inch so the fonts in the map show very small.

- I know there is high dpi images available for Android browser. (the Maps app does not count)
- I know that you can double the scale of static maps API images.

I don't know if I can get these high resolution images on an interactive Google Map. Can I do that, or am I just to stick with zoom feature (I don't like the zoom idea because it looks blurry when you zoom in)